# Are there any Shia sources that report this event?

Tags: source-identification

Are there any Shia sources that report the event mentioned in the following hadith?

> Narrated Anas:
>
> While the Prophet (ﷺ) was delivering a sermon on a Friday, a man stood
>   up and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Invoke Allah to bless us with
>   rain." (The Prophet (ﷺ) invoked Allah for rain.) So, the sky became
>   overcast and it started raining till one could hardly reach one's
>   home. It kept on raining till the next Friday when the same man or
>   another man got up and said (to the Prophet), "Invoke Allah to
>   withhold the rain from us, for we have been drowned (with heavy rain
>   )." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "O Allah! Let it rain around us and not on
>   us." Then the clouds started dispersing around Medina and rain ceased
>   to fall on the people of Medina.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Updated. How does it look now?

Comment: I see i was expecting you would emphasize some phrases in the statement but you seem to be interested in the event!